# why are policy-iteration and value-iteration methods giving different results for optimal values and optimal policy?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning, policy, value-iteration

I am currently studying dynamic programming in reinforcement learning in which I came across two concepts **Value-Iteration** and **Policy-Iteration**.  To understand the same, I am implementing the gridworld example from the Sutton which says :

> The nonterminal states are S = {1, 2, . . . , 14}. There are four
>   actions possible in each state, A = {up, down, right, left}, which
>   deterministically cause the corresponding state transitions, except
>   that actions that would take the agent off the grid in fact leave the
>   state unchanged. Thus, for instance, p(6, 1|5, right) = 1, p(7, 1|7,
>   right) = 1, and p(10, r |5, right) = 0 for all r belonging to R. This is an
>   undiscounted, episodic task. The reward is -1 on all transitions until
>   the terminal state is reached. The terminal state is shaded in the
>   figure (although it is shown in two places, it is formally one state).
>   The expected reward function is thus r(s, a, s') = 1 for all states
>   s, s' and actions a. Suppose the agent follows the equiprobable
>   random policy (all actions equally likely).

Below is the implementation of the two methods

```
class GridWorld:
    def __init__(self,grid_size = 5, gamma = 0.9, penalty = -1.0, theta = 1e-2):
        self.grid_size = grid_size
        self.discount = gamma
        self.actions = [np.array([0, -1]),
                   np.array([-1, 0]),
                   np.array([0, 1]),
                   np.array([1, 0])]
        self.action_prob = 1/len(self.actions)
        self.theta = theta
        print('action prob : ',self.action_prob)
        self.penalty_reward = penalty
        self.re_init()

    def re_init(self):
        self.values = np.zeros((self.grid_size, self.grid_size))
        self.policy = np.zeros(self.values.shape, dtype=np.int)

    def checkTerminal(self,state):
        x, y = state
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            return 1
        elif (x == self.grid_size - 1 and y == self.grid_size - 1):
            return 1
        else : 
            return 0


    def step(self, state, action):
        #print(state)
        if self.checkTerminal(state):
            next_state = state
            reward = 0
        else:
            next_state = (np.array(state) + action).tolist()
            x, y = next_state
            if x < 0 or x >= self.grid_size or y < 0 or y >= self.grid_size:
                next_state = state
            reward = self.penalty_reward     

        return next_state, reward


    def compValueIteration(self):
        new_state_values = np.zeros((self.grid_size, self.grid_size))
        policy = np.zeros((self.grid_size, self.grid_size))
        iter_cnt = 0
        while True:
            #delta = 0
            state_values = new_state_values.copy()
            old_state_values = state_values.copy()

            for i in range(self.grid_size):
                for j in range(self.grid_size):
                    values = []
                    for action in self.actions:
                        (next_i, next_j), reward = self.step([i, j], action)
                        values.append(reward + self.discount*state_values[next_i, next_j])
                    new_state_values[i, j] = np.max(values)
                    policy[i, j] = np.argmax(values)
                    #delta = max(delta, np.abs(old_state_values[i, j] - new_state_values[i, j]))
            delta = np.abs(old_state_values - new_state_values).max()        
            print(f'Difference: {delta}')
            if delta < self.theta:
                break
            iter_cnt += 1

        return new_state_values, policy, iter_cnt



    def policyEvaluation(self,policy,new_state_values):
        #new_state_values = np.zeros((self.grid_size, self.grid_size))
        iter_cnt = 0
        while True:
            delta = 0 
            state_values = new_state_values.copy()
            old_state_values = state_values.copy()
            for i in range(self.grid_size):
                for j in range(self.grid_size):
                    action = policy[i, j]
                    (next_i, next_j), reward = self.step([i, j], action)
                    value = self.action_prob * (reward + self.discount * state_values[next_i, next_j])
                    new_state_values[i, j] = value
                    delta = max(delta, np.abs(old_state_values[i, j] - new_state_values[i, j]))

            print(f'Difference: {delta}')
            if delta < self.theta:
                break
            iter_cnt += 1

        return new_state_values


    def policyImprovement(self, policy, values, actions):

        #expected_action_returns = np.zeros((self.grid_size, self.grid_size, np.size(actions)))
        policy_stable = True

        for i in range(self.grid_size):
            for j in range(self.grid_size):
                old_action = policy[i, j]
                act_cnt = 0
                expected_rewards = []
                for action in self.actions:
                    (next_i, next_j), reward = self.step([i, j], action)
                    expected_rewards.append(self.action_prob * (reward + self.discount * values[next_i, next_j]))
                #max_reward = np.max(expected_rewards)
                #new_action = np.random.choice(np.where(expected_rewards == max_reward)[0])
                new_action = np.argmax(expected_rewards)
                #print('new_action : ',new_action)
                #print('old_action : ',old_action)
                if old_action != new_action:
                    policy_stable = False
                policy[i, j] = new_action

        return policy, policy_stable



    def compPolicyIteration(self):
        iterations = 0
        total_start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            start_time = time.time()
            self.values = self.policyEvaluation(self.policy, self.values)
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            print(f'PE => Elapsed time {elapsed_time} seconds')
            start_time = time.time()

            self.policy, policy_stable = self.policyImprovement(self.policy,self.values, self.actions)
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            print(f'PI => Elapsed time {elapsed_time} seconds')

            if policy_stable:
                break

            iterations += 1

        total_elapsed_time = time.time() - total_start_time
        print(f'Optimal policy is reached after {iterations} iterations in {total_elapsed_time} seconds')
        return self.values, self.policy
```

But both of my implementations give different optimal policies and optimal values. I have followed exactly the algorithms given in the book.

**Result with Policy Iteration:**

```
values :
[[ 0.         -0.33300781 -0.33300781 -0.33300781]
 [-0.33300781 -0.33300781 -0.33300781 -0.33300781]
 [-0.33300781 -0.33300781 -0.33300781 -0.33300781]
 [-0.33300781 -0.33300781 -0.33300781  0.        ]]
****************************************************************************************************
****************************************************************************************************
policy :
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 3]
 [0 0 2 0]]
```

**Result with Value Iteration:**

```
values :
[[ 0.0 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0]
 [-1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -2.0]
 [-2.0 -3.0 -2.0 -1.0]
 [-3.0 -2.0 -1.0  0.0]]
****************************************************************************************************
****************************************************************************************************
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 3.]
 [1. 0. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 2. 0.]]
```

Also, value iteration converges after 4 iterations whereas policy iteration after 2 iterations.

Where did I go wrong? Can they give different optimal policies? But what I believe is as written in the book after 3rd iteration values we obtain are optimal.Then there must be some issues with policy iteration of my code which I am unable to see. Basically, how should I fix the policy?

Comment: pls see I have fixed policy with action 0 always for policy iteration, is it the error ?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in these lines:

**(1)** value = self.action_prob * (reward + self.discount * state_values[next_i, next_j])  
**(2)** new_state_values[i, j] = value

Here you directly assign the value you get from **only one** action. If you look at the Bellman Expectation Equation, there is a sum at the beginning for all actions. You have to consider all actions from a state, do the calculation **(1)** for all possible actions, sum them up and assign this sum in **(2)** to the new value for (i,j).

Comment: thanks for response, but if you carefully see this is a deterministic policy which means for every state there is a deterministic action. Here , initially I have kept policy to be fixed with action 0 as the action for all the states and hence the probability should be 1 i.e. pi(a/s) = 0, so we don't need to sum. Infact I was taking wrong probability pi(a/s) as 0.25, now when i changed this to 1, it is not converging. Can you look into it ?